# using find command with -print option returns an error - unknown primary or operator error

Tags: printing, find, zsh

In my directory I have a bunch of folders in each folder I have one .jpeg file. I want to extract only file names of these .jpeg files. I am using:

find . -type f -print "%P\n"

but it returns an error: find: %P\n: unknown primary or operator.

I checked on the forum that they often use "printf" command instead of "print", so I tried using it as well, but it did not work:( I also tried to use single quotation '%P\n', brackets ("%P\n") - as manual suggests. But no results.

I would be very thankful if you could help me with that.

Comment: You could use `find . -exec basename {} \;` instead.

Comment: Not all versions of `find` support a `-printf` option.

Comment: You did not say which `find` you are using. I have not seen one yet where `-print` would accept an argument.

Comment: manual says " -print  This primary always evaluates to true.  It prints the pathname of the current file to standard output.  If none of -exec, -ls,-print, -print0, or -ok is specified, the given expression shall be effectively replaced by ( given expression ) -print." if I understand in correctly of course. Appreciate you comment if I am mistaken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mashuptwice,

Your method works!

> You could use `find . -exec basename {} \;` instead.